# Potential bug with macchanger

Tags: networking, cron

I have macchanger running on startup using crontab, meaning I get a random mac address on each start up.

[image: screenshot]

The screenshot above shows that if I view my mac address using:

```
$macchanger -s eth0
```

it is different to my permanent one, but if I reset it using

```
$macchanger -p eth0
```

it says `It's the same MAC!!`, meaning my mac address is already the same as my permanent address.

Is my mac address not actually changing with crontab or is this a bug?

Comment: [How to use macchanger](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses). In particular, you must make sure that the interface is down before you change its MAC address; the method indicated in the linked documentation uses a script placed in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/` which will be called automatically by Network Manager before rising the interface(s); in the script you can check `$IFACE` to take different actions for different interfaces.

Comment: Also, please copy/paste text from console programs into questions, instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: Even [good intentions](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/) the bug [may be on Network Manager](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770611) ([also here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513)).